# Solaris NFS which client is all that traffic comming from?

Tags: solaris, nfs, openindiana

On Solaris / OpendIndiana NFS server, is the a way to get per-client stats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, via DTrace's NFS providers - http://wikis.sun.com/display/DTrace/nfsv3+Provider. Additionally you should be able to find various DTrace scripts around the net that offer NFS client statistics in a more detailed way than plain `nfsstat`.

Comment: This is great but there are problems, so I have a followup question: http://serverfault.com/questions/304753/how-to-get-nfsv3-dtrace-scripts-working-on-openindiana

Answer (score 1):

You can also install "*nfstop*" on the NFS server. On its *top*-like display, you can press "c" and see the top NFS **c**lients making the load.