# How to get nfsv3* DTrace scripts working on OpenIndiana?

Tags: solaris, nfs, openindiana, dtrace

From here http://wikis.sun.com/display/DTrace/nfsv3+Provider

on OpenIndiana

the DTrace scripts:

- nfsv3io.d
- nfsv3ops.d

are failing with:

```
probe description nfsv3:::op-* matches an unstable set of probes
```

Script nfsv3fileio.d works but one of the lines with very large Rbytes and Wbytes has the Pathname as

```
<unknown>
```

Does anyone know any details on these failures and what are the workarounds?

Comment: This question is a follow up to this answer: http://serverfault.com/questions/304682/solaris-nfs-which-client-is-all-the-traffic-comming-from/304697#304697

Answer (score 4):

The first script fails because the example is incorrect.  You can't reference `args[]` while globbing the probe in that manner (as probes matching the pattern may come and go while the enabling is still in effect, so guarantees about the type of `args[N]` can't be made).  You'd need to list each `nfs3-op-*` individually, comma separated
`nfs3:::op-read-start,nfs3:::op-write-start` etc, for each operation you care about.

For `nfsv3fileio.d` the Rbytes and Wbytes of "unknown" are very large, because they're the sum of all I/O to unknown paths (probably several, perhaps many).

The paths are `<unknown>` because the kernel only stores path information in the vnode lazily (if it happens to be present, it's stored, but it's not actively sought out).  And as such is not always available.  There are tricks that sometimes force it into place (I seem to recall that `find` across the FS in question should do it, but my memory could be playing tricks).